# Keep the duplication column values and delete the rest rows in sql

Tags: sql-server

I want to keep the duplicate rows and delete the rest rows

For example

```
Emp_no   Leave_cd
-----------------    
1234     AL
1234     AL
1234     AL
1234     BT
2345     AL
2345     AL
2345     AL
2345     AL
2345     EL
```

I want to delete the non duplicate rows based on `leave_cd` and `emp_no`.

I have tried this code but the code delete all the rows in the table

```
Delete from table 
where LEAVE_CD IN (Select leave_cd as d 
                   from table 
                   group by EMP_NO, LEAVE_CD 
                   having Count(table.leave_cd) = 1)
```

Comment: your code look fine, its work well.try "<= 1"

Comment: @KyLim the <=1 still delete all the rows..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  DELETE Table 
  --SELECT t1.*  -- uncomment this line for a preview 
    FROM Table t1
   INNER JOIN (SELECT g2.Emp_no, g2.Leave_cd 
                 FROM Table g2 
                GROUP BY g2.Emp_no, g2.Leave_cd  
                 HAVING COUNT(g2.Emp_no) = 1 ) z3  ON z3.Emp_no   = t1.Emp_no 
                                                  AND z3.LEave_cd = t1.Leave_cd
```

I am sure you have a specific use case that this makes sense to you.  However, I Never do delete code based on sub queries no matter how trivial as a general practice.